# If/else statement not working for page load

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Trying to get the portfolio section of the page to display a data-filter on page load while still maintaining the menu functionality.

Tried this if/else statement it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
if(document.getElementById("portfolio")){
 var $grid = $(".grid").isotope ({
  if(document.ready){
   filter = ".all"
  } else {
      itemSelector: ".all",
      percentPosition: true,
      masonry: {
      columnWidth: ".all"
   }
 })
};
```

I am editing a template. This is the original JS:

```
 $('.filters ul li').click(function(){
    $('.filters ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var data = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: data
    })
  });

  if(document.getElementById("portfolio")){
        var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
          itemSelector: ".all",
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: ".all"
          }
        })
  };
```

And the section of html

```
                   <div class="filters">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active" data- 
                        filter=".all">All</li>
                        <li data-filter=".web">Web</li>
                        <li data-filter=".print">Print</li>
                        <li data- 
                     filter=".interactive">Interactive</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="filters-content grid">
                    <div class="row print all portfolio">

                         <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col- 
                          xs-12">
                            <img src="img/Portfolio/SP_ads.jpg" 
                            style="width:100%;">
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col- 
                         xs-12 portfolio-text textright order-md- 
                          first">
                            <h3>Print Advertisements</h3>
                            <p>InDesign</p>
                            <h6>Full&nbsp;page magazine 
                             advertisements for a luxury petite 
                           athletic fashion&nbsp;scompany.</h6>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: would you provide us with more code, at least your `HTML`

Comment: The answer is right about `document.ready` not being a thing, but you can’t put an if statement in an object literal like that either.

Comment: mixing jquery and DOM?

Answer (score 1):

`document.ready` isn't a thing. Try `if(document.readyState === "complete"){...}` instead.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Or, if you want to use jQuery's ready function, you can leave your code as is and add this line somewhere:

```
$(()=>document.ready = true)
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

**edit:** I just realized what you were doing after seeing someone point it out in the comments.. You need to create the options object before instantiating the plugin.

```
if(document.getElementById("portfolio")){
   var options = {};
   if(document.readyState === "complete"){
      options.filter = '.all';
   }else{
      options.itemSelector = ".all";
      options.percentPosition = true;
      options.masonry = {columnWidth: ".all"};
   }
   var $grid = $(".grid").isotope(options);
};
```

Comment: While that maintains the interactivity of the menu, it does not load the page with the all filter selected. This is the site I am troubleshooting http://maria-muldoon.muldoongraphics.com/. When coding in Brackets the preview displays everything correctly. When I uploaded the site to hosting, the rows in the portfolio section started overlapping vertically. However, when you click "All" the rows display the margins correctly. I am thinking the document.readyState is the only way to go perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: code in the brackets is a syntax error, which means none of that code does anythng when there's a syntax error. if breaking the code fixes it then just remove that chunk of code entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `document.ready`with complete. Please follow this code

```
        if (document.getElementById("portfolio")) {
            var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({

                if(event.target.readyState === 'interactive') {
                    itemSelector: ".all",
                    percentPosition: true,
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: ".all"
        }
                }else if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
                    filter = ".all"
                }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the solution for the data-filter page load:

```
if(document.getElementById("portfolio")){
        var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
          itemSelector: ".all",
            **filter: ".web",**
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: ".all",
          }
        })
  };
```